# What can one say about a subscheme of a Hilbert scheme, which is covered by lines?

Tags: hilbert-schemes

k= complex numbers, X/k closed subscheme of a Grassmannian, which is Plücker embedded in a projective space. a)X is simply connected b) the first Chow group (rational coefficients)of X is generated by (the class of) a single line in X b)any two points in X(k) can be connected by a chain of lines in X.---What can one say about X ?